# jquery index within a parent class

Tags: jquery, css, count, indexing, element

I need a way to find the index number of one child element.

here is the CSS of it

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
    <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

My jquery code is like this

```
var number = $(".son").index(this);
```

When I use this code, it will count the son as a whole. Eg, when I click on the second child element in the second parent class, it will give me a var number 7. I want the son class always start counting from zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.son').index(this)
```

As other members mention:

```
$(this).index()
```

Does the job, since index() with no arguments returns position of element relative to its siblings.

Documentation:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

`$(this).index()`

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uKa7d/